# Unable to check boolean is true or false in angular method

Tags: angular, typescript

I have created this method

```
check()
{
  this.Service.GetList(data).subscribe(x=>{
    if(x.intCode == 200)
    {
      if(somecondition)
        {
         return false;
        }
        else
        {
         return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
  });
}
```

when i'm calling this method inside other method

```
if(this.check==false)
{
```

This comparison appears to be unintentional because the types 'void' and 'boolean'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your return is in the subscribe. If you were to specify a return type on your function, ex

```
check() : boolean {
..
}
```

you will notice an error stating that not all code paths returns a value. This is because observables are asynchronous and your function will only return true/false once a value is emitted from the observable. By that time, the check() function would already have been completed. Basically, the check() function won't wait for the GetList(data) to complete and just return nothing.

You can wrap your function in a promise to await the response:

```
async check() {
      return new Promise<boolean>((resolve, reject) => {
           
        this.Service.GetList(data).subscribe(x => {
          if(x.intCode == 200)
          {
            if(somecondition)
              {
               resolve(true);
              }
              else
              {
                resolve(false);
              }
          }
          resolve(false);
            },
            (error) => {
              reject();
            }
          );      
    });
  }
```

And use it as follows:

```
async myOtherMethod(){
  const res = await this.check()
  if(res){
    console.log('check is true!');
  }
  else {
    console.log('check is false!');
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can execute your myOtherMethod code in the subscribe of the check() function, or let your ckeck() function return an observable, and combine it (https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/concatmap) with myOtherMethod().

Answer (score -1):

Please refactor the cocde like this

```
  check() {
  this.Service.GetList(data).subscribe(x=>{
  this.isCheckValue = x.intCode == 200 ? 
                      (somecondition ? true : false) 
                      : false
    });
  }
```

Then check the variable

```
if(!this.isCheckValue)
```

{